# Keeping track of blog posts through a listbox control

Tags: c#, arraylist, checkedlistbox

Sorry for the erroneous title, I don't know how else to describe it.

Basically, I am reading in blog posts from a Wordpress blog's RSS feed, and then adding them to a `CheckedListBox` control.

Blog post information (post title and permalink) are stored in an `ArrayList` like so:

```
// Store post data
ArrayList post = new ArrayList();
post.Add(this.nodeItem["title"].InnerText);
post.Add(this.nodeItem["link"].InnerText);

// Store item data in posts list
posts.Add(post);
```

The ArrayList `posts` is then returned to my main form. I populate the CheckedListBox like so:

```
// Grab the latest posts
this.posts = rssReader.getLatestPosts();

// Loop through them and add to latest posts listbox
foreach (ArrayList post in posts)
{
    lbLatestPosts.Items.Add(post[0]);
}
```

After this is run, my CheckedListBox shows post titles. I want to be able to parse out information based on the post URL, which if you remember is `post[1]`. But, I'm unable to do that because I don't have a way to get `post[1]` from the CheckedListBox.

The only way I can think of doing this is looping through every item in the CheckedListBox which is checked, then comparing the post title to an element in `posts`. If they match, I have the array index to use like `post = posts[index][1]`.

I keep telling myself there must be a better way to do this, though. Is there?

Comment: Could you think of a listview instead? For a listview every item can be tagged to an object, in your case `post` so that now you get both post[0] and post[1].

Comment: I need the check boxes though to select specific posts to parse information from. I need to display the post title in the list check box, but when I finish selecting the posts and click "parse" I need to know the post URL's. Is there a way to "tag" an item to an object in `CheckedListBox`?

Comment: no there isn't. But you can instead use a checked listview..

Comment: I went with a ListView. How can I add an item as an object, though? When I do this: `lvPostQueue.Items.Add(post);` (`post` is an object) I get an error saying it can't convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkeditems.aspx). Like this:

```
listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
listView1.View = View.Details;

//Set the column headers and populate the columns.
listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Nonclickable;

ColumnHeader columnHeader1 = new ColumnHeader();
columnHeader1.Text = "Title";
columnHeader1.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
columnHeader1.Width = 146;

listView1.Columns.Add(columnHeader1);

listView1.BeginUpdate();

foreach (ArrayList post in posts)
{
    string[] postArray = new string[] { post[0].ToString() };
    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(postArray);
    listItem.Tag = post;
    listView1.Items.Add(listItem);
}

//Call EndUpdate when you finish adding items to the ListView.
listView1.EndUpdate();
```

Now you know how to get `post[1]` from listView item I guess.. Just get from Tag property. But in the end I would ask you to do away with ArrayLists..